# Does Cordova Support PHP Code

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

Instead of index.html we are using index.php in our project. But when I created ios app using cordova 5.1.1 the app cannot recognize the .php file. I tried php syntax also in index.html like  but cordova is not recognizing this also.

Is there any plugin to run php in code in cordova app?

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of Cordova:

> Apache Cordova is a set of device APIs that allow a mobile app
>   developer to access native device function such as the camera or
>   accelerometer from JavaScript. Combined with a UI framework such as
>   jQuery Mobile or Dojo Mobile or Sencha Touch, this allows a smartphone
>   app to be developed with just HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

It does not have a server to interpret PHP code. What you can do is use HTML,CSS and Javascript, along with AJAX call to the server where you can handle your PHP code there and process the result with available APIs in Cordova.

You can do something like [this example](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2011/11/10/Example-of-serverbased-login-with-PhoneGap).